# Rebuilding the LaunchServices database on Ventura only partially works

Tags: finder, file-extensions, launch-services

I use Affinity programmes on my M1 MBP running Ventura 13.3.1 and after a while have accumulated several versions of Designer, Photo and Publisher - each time I installed a new one I gave the previous one a version number, so that the new one would be the default to open files, but I could go in the Finder and right-button-click + "Open With" to open files with a specific (older) version (when facing a bug for example).
I've come to the point where I want to trim those down in the Finder, e.g. remove the Photo 1, Photo 2.0.1 and Photo 2.0.3 from the OpenWith list and just have the latest 2.0.4 (known as simply Photo).
So I have gone into each Contents folder for the Application I want to remove from the OpenWith menu, and edited the info.plist to remove any entry from the < CFBundleTypeExtensions> key; so instead of having:

```
    <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
    <array>
        <string>afphoto</string>
    </array>
```

I now have:

```
    <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
    <array></array>
```

To keep things simple, I have installed OnyX and used this to rebuild the LaunchServices database - after a reboot:

- for Publisher and Designer, the expected result was achieved
- for Photo - it seemed to not have worked: despite removing the values from CFBundleTypeExtensions the application still show in the OpenWith menu in the Finder.
  I have moved the Application Bundles from /Applications; rebuilt the LaunchServices database with OnyX and rebooted - same thing happens

I am at a loss as to why it worked for Publisher/Designer but not Photo; Google'ing does not point me in any promising direction; does anyone have an idea?